# Unknown switch error encountered when opening Terminal

Tags: 14.04, command-line

Every time that I open a new Terminal window I get this error:

```
ERROR: Unknown switch ''. Accepted values: ia32, intel64
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, I put one wired line, which was suggested to solve another problem. 
Now I deleted it and it's gone.

Comment: @g_p Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Fabby.Posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probable reason  for this problem is you have some incorrect entries in your `~/.bashrc` file.
 This file is read by the bash, whenever you start a new terminal.(See  [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) for more detail)

It may happen that you have entered some incorrect value in this file accidentally or  you are executing any script through this file, which is throwing  this error.

Search for such incorrect entries in your `~/.bashrc` and remove it.